# Can ifort and pgi complier coexist in the same system?

Tags: linux, centos, compiling

My linux cluster has installed ifort compiler now.

But for some purpose, I need pgi compiler in the same computer.

Can they coexist? I'm not familiar with this area, afraid of meeting trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be fine, using multiple compilers (Fortran or any other language) is pretty common, and their default installations shouldn't interfere with each other.

Of course, anytime you're using multiple compilers for a language, you should organize your projects so that you remember which compiler you targeted.  At a minimum, make a note in a README or INSTALL file, so that you and other users can easily compile your software in the future.